# Regarding Merging classes in Image Segmentation (Python)

Tags: python, image, cross-domain, image-segmentation, satellite-image

I'm Trying to implement Domain adaptation of Segmentation of Satellite Images From one set of images to another images.

To align the classes in two domains , I need to merge the two classes of one source.

For example i have to align ***Roads class*** and ***Buildings class*** into one class.

Can anyone give idea how to do this operation.

Comment: Example data is needed to answer this question.

Comment: I have tiff files along with ground truth values of tiff files (in terms of segmentation ). ground truth is given for classes - Roads , Buildings , Low vegetation , Trees , cars , clutter , unknown (RGB values ) . Now I have to merge Roads and Buildings ground truth values into one .

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your problem correctly but it sounds like you want to take two segmentation maps and create a union of those points for a new class `Road-Building`... If this is the case, then maybe look at the convex hull problem.

Comment: Or maybe your problem is simpler and you just want to relabel all the `Roads` as `Building` (or vice versa...what you call each is arbitrary)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.